# Encrypt/Decrypt - C Language

Tags: c, encryption

So, I'm here to ask about an encrypt and decrypt program.

That's the deal, I will ask for a key in the start of the program like:
AgFvcD
So after the key I'll ask for the message that they want to be encrypted:
Hello World!

Then I think about use ASCII code to make this as

I'll take the value of each **key(AgFvcD) character** but as **decimal value** and multiply for each **message character** as **decimal** too.

(A * H) - (g * e) - (F * l) - (v * l) - (D * o) and so on.. even if I set the key with numbers(123) it still having their Decimal ASCII value, not the number in itself.

The problem is in the multiplication, because I was thinking to use two vectors one to receive the key and the other to multiply the key over the message.
But I don't know how to make the vector multiplication, even if the key is shorter than the message, it should go back to the first key character and keep going, till the message get all encrypted.

Got it?

If it is not well explained, I'll try to make it simpler than that.

Thanks since then.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void Encrypt(){
    char text[256] = {0};
    int textc[256] = {0};
    char key[] = {0};
    int keyc[] = {0};
    int i;
    system("cls");
    printf("Type the encrypt key: ");
    fgets(key, 256, stdin);   //Recebe a chave de criptografia
    printf("\n*\n");   //Avisa sobre o limite de caracteres
    printf("Type the message: ");
    fgets(text, 256, stdin);  //Recebe a mensagem a ser criptografada
    printf("Encrypting...\n");    //Charme ; )
    //sleep(3);
    for(i=0; i<strlen(text); i++){
    textc[i]=text[i];
    key[i]= keyc[i];
    printf("\n %d \n", textc[i]*keyc[i]);
    }
    system("Pause");
    return Encrypt();
}
```

Some characters on the promp when I printf get a memory trash but the most of them bring me the right value, test with encript key: AAA and message: AAAAAAA

it will return some 4225 that's the result of 65 * 65.

The problem now is to not get back these values...

Comment: Look up the modulo `%` operator, both in C and in theory.

Comment: excuse me, but how could % modulo help me?? it just shows the rest of a division, am I sure?

Comment: Sry, but what did you try? Where did you got stuck? What explicit (C)-coding issue you are facing?

Comment: I'm stucked between make the A comes to be 65 and multiply for the other A, and when I get the end of key, get back to the start and keep going till the message is over.

Comment: Are you asking how, when looping over the characters in the key, return to the start of the key and continue looping (assuming the key length is smaller than the message)?

Comment: YEEEEEAH BRO THAT'S WHAT I'M TRYING TO SAY

Comment: This is exactly what the modulo `%` operator could be used for. `for (int i = 0; i < message_length; i++) { total -= key[i % key_length] * message[i]; }` It allows us to 'wrap around'.

Comment: @OtavioAraujo please indent your code.

Comment: What is this `return Encrypt();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

```
char key[] = {0};
int keyc[] = {0};
```

Because you don't specify a size for these arrays, it allocated just enough size for the initialized elements, meaning each array is of length 1.  When you write your key, you overrun the length of these arrays.  So you need to explicitly set the size:

```
char key[256] = {0};
int keyc[256] = {0};
```

When you use `fgets` the trailing newline gets appended to the string, so you need to strip it off:

```
fgets(key, 256, stdin);
key[strlen(key)-1] = '\0';   // strip the newline added by fgets
...
fgets(text, 256, stdin);
text[strlen(text)-1] = '\0';  // strip the newline added by fgets
```

In order to reuse key material when the key is shorter than the message, you need to separately keep track of the key index and reset it to zero when it gets too big:

```
for(i=0,j=0; i<strlen(text); i++){
    textc[i]=text[i];
    keyc[i]= key[j];   // You had these mixed up.  You were doing key[i] = keyc[i]
    printf("\n %d \n", textc[i]*keyc[i]);
    j++;
    if (j >= strlen(key)) j=0;
}
```

For efficiency's sake, you probably want to store `strlen(text)` and `strlen(key)` in separate variables before the loop so you don't recalculate them each time.  Just be sure to do this *after* you strip the newlines added by `fgets`.

One more thing: get rid of the `return Encrypt()` call at the end.  That has the function call itself recursively with no escape clause, so you get an infinite loop.

Comment: dbush You helped me a lot, the only step that I did not get is the one that you say to 
When you use fgets the trailing newline gets appended to the string, so you need to strip it off:

key[strlen(key)-1] = '\0';
text[strlen(text)-1] = '\0';

where do I need to put this? because everything is ok but as you said, but fgets adds the last space from the key so, key = (AA ) and it's multiplying for 10(the last space).

Comment: @OtavioAraujo You want to do that right after the corresponding call to `fgets`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @OtavioAraujo Also, feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: oh of course, i'm new in here so I don't know too much about the mechanics hahaha